# Why isn't my image upload showing up in my imagelocation field in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, file-upload, phpmyadmin, image-uploading

I've been toying with this for ages and can't seem to figure out why its happening - I'm following a "PhpAcademy" tutorial & have the following code (I'm simply using phpmyadmin to upload a user profile pic based on session):  The problem is when I select the file & click "upload" the image file doesn't show up in phpmyadmin under 'imagelocation'.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

THE 'UPLOADPROFILEPIC.PHP' FILE THAT SHOULD START THE UPLOAD PROCESS:

```
<?php

$_SESSION['username']="atestuser508";

$username = $_SESSION['username'];

echo "Welcome, ".$username."!<br/>";

if ($_POST['submit']) {
// get file attributes
$name = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];

if ($name)
{
    // start the upload process

    $location = "avatars/$name";
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$location);

    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET imagelocation='$location' WHERE username='$username'");

    die("You've successfully uploaded your profile pic! <a href='login-home.php'>Return to your profile</a>");
}
else
die("Please select a file to upload!");
}

echo "Upload a profile picture:

<form action='uploadprofilepic.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
File: <input type='file' name='myfile'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload!'>
</form>

";  
?>
```

THE 'PROFILE' PAGE THAT SHOULD ALLOW USER TO UPLOAD & THEN ALSO DISPLAY PROFILE PIC:

```
<?php include("uploadprofilepic.php"); ?>
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$username'");
if (mysql_num_rows($query)==0) 
die("User not found!");
else {
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$location = $row['imagelocation'];

echo "<img src='$location'>";
}
```

?>

Comment: um are you saying the imagelocation db field is empty?

Comment: actually Dagon it shows up as a zero in the db field in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is going to allow a malicious user to upload any file they want, anywhere on your server. You're blindly trusting that the `['name']` parameter is 'safe'. You have no error handling whatsoever in your code, and assume that everything's going to be just fine.

In other words, you've just opened a gaping security hole in your server that anyone with the slightest bit of interest will be able to drive a pirate ship through.

At absolute BARE minimum, you need to check for upload success this way:

```
if ($_FILES['file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    ... file was uploaded ok
} else {
    die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['file']['error']);
}
```

Do not ever trust anything the user provides. On file uploads, that is a) the filename (`['name']`), b) the file's mime type (`['type']`). Both are trivial to manipulate.

Once you've verified that the uplaod succeeded, you need to check that they actually did upload an image, and not "maliciousscript-that-gives-them-total-control.php" or "nasty_virus.exe":

```
$info = getimagesize($_FILEs['file']['tmp_name']);
if ($info === FALSE) {
    die("You didn't upload a valid image type");
}
```

Then, for the filename to store this upload file under on your server, never EVER use the user-provided name. Generate one yourself. Since you're storing details about this image in a 'members' table, use that user's member ID (you do have a primary key on that table, right?). So instead of `/site/images/userprovidedfilename.jpg`, make it `/site/images/37` (assuming that user has id 37).

Make sure the file move actually succeeds:

```
$status = move_uploaded_file($_FILEs['file']['tmp_name'], '/some/path/that/you/generated');
if ($status === FALSE) {
    die("Unable to move uploaded file to destination");
}
```

Then you update your database, checking to make sure the query actually succeeded:

```
$sql = "...";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if ($result === FALSE) {
   die(mysql_error());
}
```

This is the absolute bare minimum of what you should be doing in the way of securing your upload script. There's many more things that can be done, but this should keep you safe from all but the most determined attackers. And even if you're not being attacked, the error handling will help catch the times when things do blow up for legitimate reasons.

Comment: Hey marc, Thanks a bunch - I realize the security holes in this thing.  I don't plan to be doing anything with this for a good while (I'm just learnin')...Do me a huge favor man can you include whatever code I need to add/change & show me where it needs to go on my original code files i posted.  Don't worry about security stuff for now - I just badly need this dang image to show up in phpmyadmin 'imagelocation' field to keep me motivated on this quest to one day conquer php.  I know - i've got a long way to go.  I am in your debt, my friend...

Comment: For one, you don't seem to be connecting to mysql anywhere. so at least have `... mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error())` to see what's going on there.